# Looking for query in xml file using regex in eclipse

Tags: java, regex, eclipse

Using Regex Eclipse Search feature, I need to find queries written with IBATIS e stored in XML files.

I tried build by myself the regex string.. but without successful.

In some file XML there are queries. An example of a file :

```
<sqlMap namespace="Crediti">

 <select id="quotaVarPost50" parameterClass="qdb" resultClass="qdb">
      SELECT QDD_MAX.*
      FROM  ${schema}.QUOTEDATA QDD_MAX,
            ${schema}.ESERCIZIO ESE
      WHERE QDD_MAX.DATA_REGISTRAZIONE &gt;= #DATA_REGISTRAZIONE#
        AND QDD_MAX.TIPO_QUOTA = #TIPO_QUOTA#
        AND QDD_MAX.ANNO_RIF = #ANNO_RIF#
        AND QDD_MAX.SCO_TIPO_VARIAZIONE &lt;&gt; '04'
</select>


 <select id="allegatoCreditoDaRegDeb" parameterClass="RegistroDebitori" resultClass="stringa">
        SELECT PADRE.DESCRIZIONE
        FROM ${schema}.DECODIFICA_RELAZIONI REL
            INNER JOIN ${schema}.DECODIFICA PADRE
            ON (REL.TIPO_CODIFICA_PADRE = PADRE.TIPO_CODIFICA
                AND REL.CODICE_PADRE = PADRE.CODICE)
            INNER JOIN ${schema}.DECODIFICA FIGLIO
            ON (REL.TIPO_CODIFICA_FIGLIO = FIGLIO.TIPO_CODIFICA
                AND REL.CODICE_FIGLIO = FIGLIO.CODICE)
        WHERE REL.TIPO_RELAZIONE = 'T89'
            AND REL.CODICE_RELAZIONE = 'RP88'
            AND SYSDATE BETWEEN REL.DATA_INIZIO_VAL AND REL.DATA_FINE_VAL
            AND REL.TIPO_CODIFICA_FIGLIO = #COD_SOTTOINSIEME_ORIGINE#
            AND REL.CODICE_FIGLIO = #SCO_SOTTOINSIEME_ORIGINE#
    </select>

<delete id="deleteDomanda" parameterClass="hashmap" >
        DELETE ${schema}.VOCI_DOMANDA 
        WHERE TIPO_BILANCIO = #TIPO_BILANCIO#
            AND ANNO_ES = #ANNO_ES#
            AND PROGR_DEBITO = #PROGR_DEBITO#
            AND ID_VOCE_DOMANDA_DEBITO = #ID_VOCE_DOMANDA_DEBITO#
</delete>

</sqlMap>
```

This is an example, the real file has more and more and more statement (select, delete, update , ...)

I would like have a regex string (accepted by eclipse feature -> Search - File - Regular expression) that allow me to find the statement of a query that contains some words.

For example i looking for a query who containes the words 'TDECODIFICA_RELAZIONI' and 'TDECODIFICA'. Eclipse should find the match for the statemend that has id="allegatoCreditoDaRegDeb" (present in the example above)

[here an image of search toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHi9j.png)

Comment: This `<[^>]*\sid="allegatoCreditoDaRegDeb"[^>]*>([^<]*\b(TDECODIFICA_RELAZIONI|TDECODIFICA)\b){2}`?

Comment: Thanks for the answer but, i don't know witch is the ID name of the select. I only know that i'm looking for a select "<select>??????</select>"  that contains the words that i put in the regex string.

Comment: I see. `<select[^>]*>([^<]*\b(TDECODIFICA_RELAZIONI|TDECODIFICA)\b){2}`, right?

Comment: i tried this one too when i first read your comment, but doeasn't work

Comment: It works for me with the given example. Make sure not having preceding or trailing spaces in the search field.

Comment: YOU right, works. but i need that both must be present, noy only one. for example: <select[^>]*>([^<]*\b(TDECODIFICA|BLABLABLA)\b){2} return a match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@howlger Answers with `<select[^>]*>([^<]*\b(TDECODIFICA_RELAZIONI|TDECODIFICA)\b){2}`
This regex string allow me to restrict a lot the researching.
It will match a select statement when found at least 2 result (even if the matchies could be even 2 time of one of the same word).

Thanks 
@howlger

Comment: To match each word only once use `<select[^>]*>[^<]*\b(TDECODIFICA_RELAZIONI|TDECODIFICA)\b[^<]*\b(?!\1)(TDECODIFICA_RELAZIONI|TDECODIFICA)\b` (`(?!\1)` means not the same as matched in the first parentheses).